# Android: odd issue involving hardware acceleration?

Tags: android

My app allows the user to draw on the screen by capturing and processing touch events.  Additionally, my application makes use of Canvas.drawPicture and some other methods not supported by hardware acceleration.

On some ICS devices there is an option to force hardware acceleration in settings: "force gpu rendering, use 2d harware acceleartion in applciations".  When this is enabled, my application crashes with error: `android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawPicture(GLES20Canvas.java:895)`.  So, I explicitly disabled hardware acceleration on the View that uses this method with: `View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

However, disabling hardware acceleration in this way impacts the performance of my drawing, the drawing gets "choppy", as if less MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE are being generated.  This happens on all 3.0+ devices, regardless of if the "force acceleration" setting is on.

So, I figure that there was something in the View's LayerType which was assisting my drawing, and that this is lost when I call `View.setLayerType(...)`.  Prior to my call to `View.setLayerType(...)`, View.getLayerType() evaluates to LAYER_TYPE_NONE.

Any suggestions as to how to explicitly prevent Hardware Acceleration while preserving whatever it is that was assisting my touch input?

Comment: I don't have such a suggestion, but you might [report this as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list), that the documented way to avoid hardware acceleration has this side effect.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the layer type to software you force the system to basically draw your view into bitmap. Thus inducing some extra overhead when drawing. This could be a cause of the poor performance.
I assume that your crash is due to the use of some canvas api calls that you are doing which are not supported by hardware acceleration. The following calls are currently not supported:

- clipPath
- clipRegion
- drawPicture
- drawPoints
- drawPosText
- drawTextOnPath
- drawVertices

Also note that when hardware acceleration is active any lines that you draw will look jagged as anti aliasing isn't supported then.

So you could try to either remove any calls which are not supported and use hardware acceleration or try to further optimize yoursoftware rendering:

- don't create objects like paths or bitmaps during your draw calls
- cache your Pictures into a Bitmap
- set the pixel format of the window to RGB565 (only if you need no alpha)

  getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);